# HSQLDB: Unable to delete interlocking tables and can't delete the foreign keys due to "user lacks priviledge or object not found

Tags: java, sql, jpa, hsqldb, razorsql

I am trying to drop two experimental tables from an HSQLDB server database. But, every attempt has failed, due to auto-generated foreign keys. Short of blowing away the entire database on the file system, I am running out of ideas, and would appreciate any pointers or suggestions that y'all may have.

The tables and indexes were created by JPA.  The generated DDL for the tables is:

```
CREATE TABLE SUDOKU.DIVISION (
    DIVISION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    DIVISION_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    CHIEF_EMPLOYEE_ID BIGINT,
    DEPUTYCHIEF_EMPLOYEE_ID BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (DIVISION_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE SUDOKU.EMPLOYEE (
    EMPLOYEE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    DIVISION_ID BIGINT,
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
);
ALTER TABLE SUDOKU.DIVISION
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (CHIEF_EMPLOYEE_ID,DEPUTYCHIEF_EMPLOYEE_ID) 
    REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID);

ALTER TABLE SUDOKU.EMPLOYEE
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (DIVISION_ID) 
    REFERENCES DIVISION (DIVISION_ID);
```

When I attempt to delete either table, the drop fails with the error message similar to the following `ERROR: is referenced by FOREIGN KEY constraint: SUDOKU.FKSPXEERGASS9WA2IXFLHC20IOY in statement [DROP TABLE SUDOKU.DIVISION] Error Code: -5533`

So, then I try to delete the 'foreign key' that is referenced, and that 
fails with the error message `user lacks privilege or object not found`.

I am not able to find either of the foreign keys, that are referenced in the error message, using either **RazorSQL**, or the **JPA view in Eclipse Neon-3**.

A strange thing that I noticed was that the foreign key that is referenced in the error message, changes.  It seems to depend on which tool I use to connect with.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the columns EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME, then the DIVISION table, then the EMPLOYEE table? Wfm on mysql server...
Otherwise you'll have to find the constraints and drop them first I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution:

```
 DROP TABLE SUSOKU.DIVISION CASCADE
```

Similarly when you want to delete the data from tables that have FK references:

```
 TRUNCATE TABLE SUSOKU.DIVISION AND COMMIT NO CHECK
```